# "Cannot convert value of type 'T'..." in generics

Tags: swift, generics, types, casting

Cannot understand how to treat the types of generics and how to use the arguments with the undefined types with libraries:

```
func cellWith<T>(value: T) -> String {         // I expect Int, Double or String 
                                               // type value as argument  

    let fm = NSNumberFormatter()               // Double type argument will be
    fm.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle            // processed like "currency"

    if value.self is Double {               // In case value have type "Double", 
                                            // like 20_000.00
        return(fm.stringFromNumber(value))  // I expect return $20,000.00
                                   ^~~~~
// ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'

    } else {
        return("bla-bla-bla")
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `Any` instead of a generic method. Anyway you cast in swift by doing this `if let doubleValue = value as? Double { ...use }`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: it is works with `return(fm.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double:doubleValue))!)`. I do not know, but why I should unwrap String value at the end?

Comment: Because `stringFromNumber(_:)` is not guaranteed to return a non-nil value, but your method is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to use generics in this case? Use generics only when you have to conserve type information.

Use generics only when :

> "you are going to give you a type later and I want you to enforce that
>   type everywhere I specify."

Use `Any` only when you want to tell the compiler:

> "Don't worry about this variable no need to enforce any type here let
>   me do whatever I want to."

With that said, your use case fits the second one. You do not want to mess with generics here. Your solution should go:

```
func cellWith(value: Any) -> String {
    let fm = NSNumberFormatter()
    fm.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    if let doubleValue = value as? Double {
        return(fm.stringFromNumber(doubleValue))!
    } else {
        return("bla-bla-bla")
    }
}
```

Comment: Not `return(fm.stringFromNumber(doubleValue))!` but `return(fm.stringFromNumber(doubleValue)!)`

Comment: Both are fine. You can even lose the outer parentheses. It's not enforced in Swift unlike other languages. :)